# XGetImage as PNG?

Tags: c++, xlib

Is there a way to save the XYPixmap from XGetImage as PNG or JPEG? I've tried [this code](http://www.codemadness.nl/downloads/xscreenshot.c),
but it resolved in a corrupt .png file. 
Can anyone help me with this?

  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution? :)

Comment: https://hamberg.no/erlend/posts/2011-01-06-read-current-x-background-to-jpeg.html